# $\Bbb{R}^3$ and a three dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R^4}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Lets say we have $\Bbb{R}^3$ and a three dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{R^4}$, call it $E$. Why is it that these spaces are not the same vector space? Does it have something to do with bases?

Comment: It has to do with the elements themselves.  Elements of $\Bbb R^3$ are vectors with three entries each.  Elements of $\Bbb R^4$, even those of $E$, are vectors with *four* entries each.  The elements do not look the same.  They are not the same "shape"

Comment: Now... if you were to look at the subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ where the fourth entry is always zero... yes, that space is *very similar to* $\Bbb R^3$.  They are isomorphic, homeomorphic, all sorts of ---morphic to eachother, has many of the same properties, however are not *equal*.

Comment: You might simplify things by looking at a simpler problem which can be visualized. What are the subspaces of dimension $2$ in $\Bbb R^3$. All the planes passing through the origin are such subspaces. One of these has the equation $x+y+z=0$ This is not $\Bbb R^2$ but by a rotation, it can be brought back to a copy of $\Bbb R^2$ imbedded in $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A three dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is the span of 3 linearly independent vectors, say $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$. We know at least a bare minimum about these vectors, namely that they are 4-tuples.

Meanwhile, $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the span of 3 linearly independent 3-tuples. They cannot be the same space because the vectors are different; a 3-tuple is not a 4-tuple. The intuition you're getting at is that these spaces are isomorphic; for all intents and purposes their structure is the same.